# Can I Open PhoneGap project without config.xml file?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli, phonegap-desktop-app

Is there any possibilities that the phonegap project without config.xml file? Since I am new to phonegap so I need help. When I try to open phonegap project phonegap desktop shows me an error that

> "Selected folder doesn't contain config.xml file"

But there is no config.xml file in the project in anywhere.How can I open Phonegap project without config.xml file. Can I open it without `config.xml` file?

Answer (score 0):

Config.xml file is required for any phonegap project.